How can I get model summary from a Object Detection API model?
I am working with https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection, where I have loaded the following model using pipeline config:
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.builders import model_builder

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
pipeline_config = 'models/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.config'
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

detection_model.summary()  # AttributeError: 'SSDMetaArch' object has no attribute 'summary'

I have also tried restoring the weights / variables, but to no avail
image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(tf.zeros([1, 640, 640, 3]))
prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)

for variable in detection_model.variables:
    variable.summary()  # Throws AttributeError, since none of these have .summary()

I have tensorflow version 2.10.1.
